# Fixing broken thumbnail previews

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-explorer, windows-registry, thumbnails

I'm not 100% this is the right place to post this, so please let me know if so.

A while back I had to develop a custom thumbnail preview for a file format for a piece of software I was working on. I started on this computer, before moving it over to a new work computer midway through the process.

Later I went to de-register the (half finished, non functional) IThumbnailProvider from this machine, and something went wrong.

I no longer have thumbnail previews of jpg or png files.

**I have Always Show Icons *unchecked* and I have cleared the icon and thumbnail caches many times.**

This relates to the thumbnail guid you add into shellex in the registry for specific file types, hence why I thought it might be appropriate here.

---

**Is there a way to repair my thumbnail handlers in Windows?**